# How to keep calling a function with different arguments until it succeeds in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I have a function which calls another function which can return something or Nothing depending on certain conditions. What I am wondering is, if it returns nothing how do I call it again with different arguments.

Say for example I have a function which can return times at 30 minute intervals, and the other function can only not return nothing at a certain time i.e.:

```
certainTimeFunction :: (Int,Int,Int) -> Maybe String
certainTimeFunction (h,m,s) =
    | (11,00,00) = Just "It's eleven o'clock"
    | otherwise = Nothing

timeFunction :: (Int,Int,Int) -> (Int,Int,Int)
timeFunction time = certainTimeFunction time
```

And time has to start with (00,00,00) which of course will return Nothing but then (00,30,00) is tried which again return Nothing until (11,00,00) which then triggers the function to return what is in the first guard, then the whole cycle should end.

Comment: Are you wanting to just supply it with times until one returns a `Just` value?  Also, you should have `| (11,00,00) = Just "It's eleven o'clock"`.  It also might be worth it to look at the `time` module (included in the haskell platform) for managing time-like values.

Comment: Yes until the Just value is returned.

Answer (score 6):

As always in Haskell, the answer is to use recursion!

```
timeFunction :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
timeFunction time0 = case certainTimeFunction time0 of
  Nothing  -> timeFunction (perturbTime time0)
  Just res -> res
```

Note that `perturbTime` and `certainTimeFunction` should be carefully tuned to work together as it's very easy in a circumstance like this to build an infinite loop. A cleaner way would be to "unroll" the recursion into a lazy list using `iterate`.

First we create an infinite list of "all perturbations"

```
... iterate perturbTime :: [(Int, Int, Int)]
```

then we `map` `certainTimeFunction` to check whether any such perturbation returns `Just`.

```
... map certainTimeFunction . iterate perturbTime :: [Maybe (Int, Int, Int)]
```

then we can recover the exact behavior of `timeFunction` by dropping all of the `Nothing`s.

```
timeFunction = fromJust . head . dropWhile isNothing 
             . map certainTimeFunction 
             . iterate perturbTime
```

We could also create a version of `timeFunction` which fails if `perturbTime` doesn't reach a successful point within `n` perturbations

```
timeFunctionN n = safeJustHead 
                . dropWhile isNothing
                . take n
                . map certainTimeFunction 
                . iterate perturbTime
  where safeJustHead :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a  -- note this is just `msum`
        safeJustHead []    = Nothing          -- it's also easy to implement
        safeJustHead (x:_) = x                -- using `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`
                                              -- per @bheklilr's comment below
```

Comment: You're a faster typist than I am, and you've got a far more comprehensive answer.  Also, why not use the `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe` function instead of defining your own `safeHead`?  It does the same thing.

Comment: Ha—because I thought that was in `safe` not `base`. The semantics of `safeJustHead` are also a little different—it's really `msum`! It could be written `join . listToMaybe`, though.

Comment: (I also cheated and just let `perturbTime` be out of scope so I didn't have to think about `div` ;)

Comment: This is true, you could use the `MonadPlus` instance, but the source for `listToMaybe` simply does the same pattern match exactly as you have, so it's probably a bit faster.  It also requires another import of `Control.Monad` when all you really need is `Data.Maybe`, and you're already doing so for `isNothing`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to feed it times at 30 minute intervals until one succeeds, you could do

```
import Data.Maybe

timeFunction :: (Int, Int, Int) -> (Int, Int, Int)
timeFunction initialTime = head $ catMaybes $ map certainTimeFunction times
    where
        add30 (h, m, s) =
            let newM = m + 30
                newH = h + newM `div` 60
            in (newH, newM `mod` 60, s)
        times = iterate add30 initialTime
```

This will lazily compute all increments of 30 minutes from your initial time (my `add30` is @JAbrahamson's `perturbTime`), then `certainTimeFunction` is mapped to all of those times, then `catMaybes` compresses this to the `Just` values (lazily, again), and the first one is taken.  Beware, if you don't get a time that `certainTimeFunction` returns a successful value from, this will loop forever!

If you want to stop when the hours are greater than 23, just use our good friend `takeWhile` and change `times` to

```
times = takeWhile (\(h', _, _) -> h' < 24) $ iterate add30 initialTime
```

And change the type of `timeFunction` to `Time -> Maybe String`

---

And this is a great example of why you should define your own type instead of using a tuple.  If you had

```
data Time = Time
    { hours :: Int
    , minutes :: Int
    , seconds :: Int
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Then some helper functions

```
import Data.Function (on)

asSeconds :: Int -> Time
asSeconds x = Time (x `div` 3600) (x `div` 60 `mod` 60) (x `mod` 60)

asMinutes :: Int -> Time
asMinutes = asSeconds . (* 60)

asHours :: Int -> Time
asHours x = asMinutes . (* 60)

toSeconds :: Time -> Int
toSeconds (Time h m s) = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

(+:) :: Time -> Time
(+:) = asSeconds .: on (+) toSeconds where (.:) = (.).(.)

timeFunction :: Time -> Maybe Time
timeFunction initialTime = listToMaybe $ catMaybes $ map certainTimeFunction times
    where
        times = takeWhile ((< 23) . hours) $ iterate (+: asMinutes 30) initialTime
```

which can be written more cleanly as

```
timeFunction = listToMaybe . catMaybes
             . map certainTimeFunction
             . takeWhile ((< 24) . hours)
             . iterate (+: asMinutes 30)
```

You could also make `Time` an instance of `Ord` really easily

```
instance Ord Time where
    compare = on compare toSeconds

timeFunction = listToMaybe . catMaybes
             . map certainTimeFunction
             . takeWhile (< asHours 24)
             . iterate (+: asMinutes 30)
```

Comment: Thanks how would I end it if (23,30,00) is reached before a solution is found?

Comment: @user3094936 Check my changes.

Comment: @user3094936 I've made some updates now, the code is a lot shorter and cleaner because I realized I was repeating myself too much.  I also imported `Data.Function.on` to simplify a few expressions.  What's interesting is that with just one more helper function, you could write all of this code in rather nice pointfree notation other than `asSeconds` and `toSeconds`.